# c++ cout command is frozen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to print out current hours at a specific minute, I check the current minute every 5 seconds and then put into sleep. Sounds like a simple one, but get a problem: after 2 hours, the "cout" line is frozen, here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct tm timenow;
    time_t t;
    do 
    {
        t = time(0);
        localtime_s(&timenow,&t);
        if (timenow.tm_min == 30)
        {
            cout << "current hour = " << timenow.tm_hour << endl;//frozen here
        }
        Sleep(5000);
    } while (!(timenow.tm_hour == 20 && timenow.tm_min == 00 ));
    return 0;
}
```

Then I debug into the code, looks like it stops in write.c, at the following line:

```
            /* write the lf buf and update total */
            if ( WriteFile( (HANDLE)_osfhnd(fh),
                        lfbuf,
                        (int)(q - lfbuf),
                        (LPDWORD)&written,
                        NULL) )
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How often, if ever,  are you expecting `if (timenow.tm_min == 30)` to be true, given that Sleep() doesn't have any specified granularity.?

Comment: It is once in an hour; everytime the clock hits the 30th minute, but cout is called 12 times within the minute since it sleeps 5000ms .

Comment: As I pointed out, Sleep() is simply not that accurate.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how it causes the freezing at "cout".